# How to Structure React and bootstrap-react projects?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to Structure React and bootstrap-react projects?
Here you can see my folder structure. Is this the best practice?

```
|-COPYRIGHT.md
|-dist
|  |-app
|    |-bundle.js
|    |-bundle.js.map
|
|-index.html
|-.git
|-.gitignore
|- node_modules
|-package.js
|-README.md
|
|-src
|  |-app
|  |  |-components
|  |  |  |-Footer.js
|  |  |  |-Header.js
|  |  |  |-Home.js
|  |  |
|  |  |-index.js
|  |
|  |-css
|  |  |-bootstrap.min.css
|  |  |-footer.css
|  |  |-header.css
|  |  |-styles.css
|  |
|  |-fonts
|  |  |-glyphicons-halflings
|  |
|  |-images
|  |  |-logo.jpg
|  |
|  |-index.html
|  |
|  |-js
|  |  |-es5-sham.min.js
|  |  |-es5-shim.min.js
|  |  |-html5shiv.min.js
|  |  |-html5shiv-printshiv.min.js
|  |  |-react-bootstrap.js
|  |  |-react-bootstrap.min.js
|
|-webpack.config.js
```

In the next step I would make my homepage multilingual. I need three languages de, en, fr.

1. I would like separate the languages like this.
2. How to change the languages in the Navbar?

Which of you has something already programmed and sends me a link of his Github repository? How do I program the routes correctly? In Footer I'll use three images as a flag for switching languages. But to be recognized by the browser language principle.

```
|-Languanges
  |-de
  |  |-Impressum.js
  |
  |-en
  |  |-Imprint.js
  |
  |-fr
  |  |-empreinte.js
```